# Sharing venv python packages to optimise docker image size

Tags: python, docker, pip

I have a docker container where I am installing multiple versions of a package into different venvs so that users of the docker image can quickly change between the package using `PATH` env to point to the version they want.

However this docker image is currently growing massively and taking a long time to build. I was wondering is there any way to optimise the process to both reduce the build time and the actual size of the image.

---

I have a for loop of different `$version`s with a requirements.txt for each:

```
python3 -m venv "package-$version"
source package-$version/bin/activate

# install dbt deps
which python3
# pip install --upgrade pip
export PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1

pip config set global.parallel true
pip config set global.prefer-binary true

python -m pip install --requirement "resources/requirements/requirements.$version.txt"
```

Comment: This sounds like a task for multiple docker images with appropriate tags.

Comment: check for multi-stage builds

Comment: @KlausD. the problem is, is I want the user inside the docker container to be able to switch between these venvs quickly

Comment: What is the single process the container is running?  Once the container's `CMD` has started the Python process, it can't switch virtual environments or Python runtimes.  I'd go with @KlausD.'s advice and build a separate image for each variant.